# Grid View Custom View issue : java.lang.ClassCastException?

Tags: android, gridview, classcastexception

I am writing an application where requirement is to dimply drawable in two column sequence. 
This is my Adapter.getView(..) implementation:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ImageView imageView = null;

            if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

                View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent);
                imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);

            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageView.setImageResource(drawable[position]);
            return imageView;
        }
```

But while to convert it ,,it responding with following error log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(10419): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.AbsListView$LayoutParams
E/AndroidRuntime(10419):    at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1056)
E/AndroidRuntime(10419):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15356)
```

Any suggestion what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this, add `return convertView;`

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final ViewHolder mHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);
        mHolder = new ViewHolder();
        mHolder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);
        convertView.setTag(mHolder);

    } else {
        mHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    try {
     imageView.setImageResource(drawable[position]);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }

    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    private ImageView imageView;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you are returning imageView instead of your view which you inflated
Write this.

```
  return view ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change this.

```
 if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

      convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent);
      imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.picture);

 } else {
       imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
       }

 imageView.setImageResource(drawable[position]);
 return convertView;
```

OR

```
 View view = convertView ;

  if (view == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes

      view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent);
      imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.picture);

 } else {
      imageView = (ImageView) view;
 }

 imageView.setImageResource(drawable[position]);
 return view ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your view has been attached to parent, try this:

```
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
```

and

```
return view;
```